# Implicit conversion rules when assigning to an iloc call

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I noticed the following awkward line of implicit conversions when using iloc:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[3,2,1]},dtype=np.int_) # x has dtype int

df.iloc[0,0] = np.nan # now x gets dtype float

df.iloc[1,0] = None # I would have expected dtype object - but no, the None is converted to a Nan and the dtype stays the same
```

So, can someone explain the exact rule that is used internally? I thought that the broadest dtype is searched that can cope with all the given values. But apparently this isn't true.

Or put in another way: When is the dtype converted to cope with a given value and when is the value converted to the given dtype?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is before all designed to work with numeric values (integers, floats, dates…), so I believe the fact that None is treated as NaN makes sense.

Even if you force an object dtype, pandas will use None as NaN:

```
s = pd.Series({df.index[1]: None}, dtype='object')
s.dtype
# dtype('O')

df.iloc[1,0] = s
df.dtypes
# x    float64
# dtype: object
```

Note that an exception would be to use a list to slice the row:

```
df.iloc[[1], 0] = s
df.dtypes
# x    object
# dtype: object

print(df)
#       x
# 0   NaN
# 1  None
# 2   1.0
```

Comment: Well I can get the desired behavior by using:df = df.astype(object)
df.iloc[1,0] = None

Comment: @P.Jo of course here you convert explicitly the DataFrame to object